# C++: What are the differences between the positions and index

Tags: c++, list, indexing, position, sequences

Can somebody please explain to me the differences (or the similarities) between the position and index of elements in context of sequences and lists in C++ ?
(I was reading the implementation of Sequences using an array and why it had to be done a certain way. The array elements were holding pointers to elements that had held information about the index of the element and the useful value. )

Comment: Sounds like something course-specific. It's certainly not in common use.

Comment: @molbdnilo That crossed my mind. I also thought he was referring to iterators?

Comment: I am sorry if the question was not making sense earlier, does it now?

Comment: @Borgleader : Yes this is related to providing iterators for the sequence.